Derivation of pressure in a fluid
I have a quick conceptual question regarding derivation of pressure at a depth in a fluid. When deriving the equation, we say that the fluid is in a static condition, which I understand to mean that there is no movement of particles in the fluid. Looking at the image below, I have labeled the pressure $P_1$ as the pressure of the fluid at this specific height $h$.
For the fluid to be static, this must mean that the force pushing that white section of liquid down equals the force pushing it up. This must mean that $F_1=F_2$ and $P_1=P_2$ since $F=\frac{P}{A}$ and $A$ is the same in both cases. I'm confused how it is possible that the smaller amount of liquid at the bottom (in purple) is able to exert the same force (or pressure) as the liquid on top (in orange). And if that is not the case, then how is the fluid static? To be clear, the two liquids are the same, just colored differently for visualization purposes.
Furthermore, how can we be certain of the fact then that $F_2$ is the maximum force the liquid can exert at height $h$? For example, with friction we know that there is some max force of static friction that the surface can exert, after which the object starts to move. However, for any force applied smaller than that, the force of friction equals the force exerted on the object (resulting in no movement).
Therefore, how do we know that the liquid is not capable of exerting a greater force up than $F_2$? The implications of this have to do with the buoyant force, as this would mean that it could perhaps change or be greater than $\rho gh$ with respect to height. Of course I know this is not true, however, if someone could help resolve these questions for me I would be greatful!


In your figure $P_1$ is the sum total of all the weight of the fluid above, while $P_2$ comes from the bulk rigidity of the fluid below resisting compression.  Imagine replacing your white sheet with a very thin piston.  As in a hydraulic cylinder, the piston stays in position because the fluid below it cannot be compressed to a smaller volume.  It is essentially the same as resting on a solid surface via a normal force.
As for your second point on friction – this concerns a very important feature of fluids in general: they cannot sustain constant shear forces.  In many ways this is the definition of a fluid (which can be liquid or gas).  For example, if you have a small boat floating in the water, and pull on it with a rope from land.  The water will resist as the boat is moving, but once the boat is at the new position, the water will adjust and the resistance will completely dissipate when the boat is stationary.  You would have to keep the boat in motion (or else have a current in the opposite direction) to maintain tension in the rope.  This is in contrast to, say, pulling a heavy slab over concrete.  You can sustain quite a lot of tension in the rope indefinitely, without the slab moving, because of the shear resistance in the solid ground.$^†$
With this said, hopefully it is easy to see that the walls of the container in your image could not counteract any of the weight of the fluid, because this would require transmitting shear forces through the fluid - provided that the fluid has had time to reach a steady condition.  If the container is narrow and the fluid very viscous like honey, it may take some time after being poured in for the fluid to stop sliding down the walls, and during this transient period some fluid weight may be counteracted by wall friction.
$^†$ This is basically the reason that until the 19th Century, nearly all transport and commerce was via waterways rather than land.

Hello, thank you for your response! I have a follow up question about this. You mentioned that the upwards pressure comes from the bulk rigidity of the fluid trying not to be compressed. This I understand! But then when there's an object submerged, why is the pressure still equal to $\rho gh$? Shouldn't it be trying to resist being compressed by both the mass of the object and the water above it? Or is this related to your point about sheer forces? I apologize in advance if any of those questions don't make sense or are supposed to be common knowledge! I'm a little new to this stuff.
